# Disable plus/minus buttons if number input max/minus attribute is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce project. For those unfamiliar with WooCommerce, it sports a lot of number inputs with dynamically-added corresponding +/- buttons to control the quantity of a product you're adding to the cart. What I'm trying to do is disable the +/- buttons when the number input reaches its `max` or `min` attribute. If no `max` or `min` attribute is set, min should default to 0 and max to 999. On page load, if the number input `value` starts out at the `min` or a `max` (or a the fallback if neither `min` or `max` is set), the appropriate button should be disabled immediately without waiting for `.change()` on the number input to be fired.

**HTML** (pre buttons added)

```
<div class="quantity">
    <input type="number" step="1" max="20" name="" value="1" class="qty">
</div>
```

**HTML** (post buttons added)

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
    <input type="number" step="1" max="20" name="" value="1" class="qty">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
</div>
```

**WooCommerce JS**

```
$("div.quantity:not(.buttons_added), td.quantity:not(.buttons_added)").addClass('buttons_added').append('<input type="button" value="+" class="plus" />').prepend('<input type="button" value="-" class="minus" />');

$("input.qty:not(.product-quantity input.qty)").each(function () {
    var min = parseFloat($(this).attr('min'));

    if (min && min > 0 && parseFloat($(this).val()) < min) {
        $(this).val(min);
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.plus, .minus', function () {

    var $qty = $(this).closest('.quantity').find(".qty");
    var currentVal = parseFloat($qty.val());
    var max = parseFloat($qty.attr('max'));
    var min = parseFloat($qty.attr('min'));
    var step = $qty.attr('step');

    if (!currentVal || currentVal == "" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
    if (max == "" || max == "NaN") max = '';
    if (min == "" || min == "NaN") min = 0;
    if (step == 'any' || step == "" || step == undefined || parseFloat(step) == "NaN") step = 1;

    if ($(this).is('.plus')) {
        if (max && (max == currentVal || currentVal > max)) {
            $qty.val(max);
        } else {
            $qty.val(currentVal + parseFloat(step));
        }
    } else {
        if (min && (min == currentVal || currentVal < min)) {
            $qty.val(min);
        } else if (currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - parseFloat(step));
        }
    }

    $qty.trigger('change');
});
```

**My JS**

```
$.fn.disableNumberButtons = function () {
    var value = this.val();

    var minus = this.prev();
    var minAttr = this.attr('min'); 
    var min = (minAttr) ? minAttr : 0;
    (value > min) ? minus.removeClass('is-disabled') : minus.addClass('is-disabled');

    var plus = this.next();
    var maxAttr = this.attr('max');
    var max = (maxAttr) ? maxAttr : 999;
    (value < max) ? plus.removeClass('is-disabled') : plus.addClass('is-disabled');
}

$('input.qty').each(function () {
    $(this).disableNumberButtons();
});

$('input.qty').change(function () {
    $(this).disableNumberButtons();
});
```

**Problem**

If I increase the value of `input[type="number"]` to between 3 and 10 it disables the plus button. Once I get the value above 10, it re-enables it until the value reaches 20, the value of the `max` attribute, where it should be disabled. What gives?

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/a4RjS/

Comment: you have many errors in your js file i have correct them for you , check now http://jsfiddle.net/a4RjS/2/

Comment: That did the trick. What exactly was I doing wrong? Was it not wrapping `value` in `parseFloat`?

Comment: actually i don't remember i was drunk :) , but its not because wrapping value in parseFloat ,  for example you was setting the value again if min-max by parseFloat , i correct it to be min--, max++ this is better and many lines has been corrected don't ask me what they are , try to compare ^_^